# Ubuntu 9.04 not creating LAN connection

Tags: lan, 9.04

I installed Ubuntu 9.04 on my HP Probook. It's processor is Intel Core i3 and RAM is 8GB. I am not able to create a LAN connection. How can I connect it from my LAN connection.

Thanks

Comment: It would be 9.04 , which is no longer supported. You can give a try to Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 (Very Recent release, last 2 days).

Comment: I second that you should try Ubuntu 12.10 if you have the possibility. Otherwise, we need some information to be able to help you; post the contents of terminal commands `lspci` and `sudo lshw -c network`.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 9.04 was released in April, 2009. As a normal release, it was supported until October, 2010. These are the current supported releases:

- Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx (until April, 2013)
- Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal (until the end of October, 2012)
- Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot (until April, 2013)
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin (until April, 2017)
- Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal (until April, 2012)

Ubuntu 12.10 is the newest release, so it has better hardware support than Ubuntu 12.04, but it is supported only until the end of April in 2014. I recommend you to choose Ubuntu 12.10.